# Display images from a folder on a php page

Tags: php

i want to retrieve images from the specific folder and display on a php page. i have tried the following code. but it only shows the path and not the image.Instead, it shows the alt message.

```
<?php
 $files = glob("C:/Users/bisha/Pictures/Picasa Edits/*.*"); 
 for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) 
 {
    $num = $files[$i]; print $num."<br />"; 
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" />'."<br /><br />"; 
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images should be in a web accessible place.

Comment: But i want to display images stored on my desktop. I want to use this path as well.     glob("C:/xampp/htdocs/SYT/UploadedFiles/*.*");    So, can you help to display images stored at this path.

Comment: This path should work if you have the right absolute/relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your images are outside of your testing software, if you're using XAMPP or WAMP, you'll have to move your pictures from your picture folder into a folder that your server has access to.

Neither XAMPP nor WAMP have access to anything of the folders where they were installed on.

** edit ** 
This is the function I use to get images from a folder: ( I know the function is very rough, but it's used only in a small part of a program that I wrote, edit to your needs )

```
<?php
//$dir = directory
function get_images($dir)
{
$rv = '';

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir))
{
  if($dh = opendir($dir))
  {
    // start json
    $json_data = '';

    // put data into Json
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
        {
            $json_data .= "{
                    image: '".$dir.$file."',
                    thumb: '".$dir.$file."'
                    },";
        }
    }

    // remove trailing comma
    $rv = rtrim($json_data, ',');

    // close folder
    closedir($dh);
  }// /open dir
}// /check dir

return $rv;
}
?>
```

Comment: i tried with this path also but it doesnt works.   glob("C:/xampp/htdocs/SYT/UploadedFiles/*.*");

Comment: once you put everything in the same folder, don't use the entire path,
Start from:
glob("SYT/UploadedFiles/*.*");

Comment: i have tried this but not working.i want to display the images stored on this path only. can you help me in detail.

Comment: Play around with the function that posted, that 1 is working perfectly for me, echo it out and try different paths.